# Postgres - fill in missing data in new table

Tags: postgresql

Given two tables, A and B:

```
A            B
-----        -----
id           id
high         high
low          low
bId
```

I want to find rows in table A where `bId` is null, create an entry in B based off the data in A, and update the row in A to reference the newly created row. I can create the rows but I'm having trouble updating table A with the reference to the new row:

```
begin transaction;

with rows as (
    insert into B (high, low)
    select high, low
    from A a
    where a.bId is null
    returning id as bId, a.id as aId
)
update A
set bId=(select bId from rows where id=rows.aId)
where id=rows.aId;

--commit;
rollback;
```

However, this fails with a cryptic error: `ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table a`.

Using a Postgres query, how can I achieve this?

Comment: Start by not using `rows` as an identifier. (and:I would avoid the scalar subquery, too)

Comment: Also, column identifiers are case insensitive.  Best to use lower case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

either

```
update "A"
set "bId"=(select "bId" from rows where id=rows."aId")
```

without the where clause or

```
update "A"
set "bId"=(select "bId" from rows where id=rows."aId")
FROM rows
where "A".id=rows.aId;
```

I dont know if your tables realy have that names, as mentioned in the comments try to avoid uppercase tables and fieldnames and try to avoid reserved keynames.

Comment: Thanks, the table names aren't really like that, I simplified the names and columns simply for example purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to get it to work but I feel like it's not the most efficient.

```
begin transaction;
do $body$
declare 
    newId int4;
    tempB record;
begin
create temp table TempAB (
    High float8,
    Low float8,
    AID int4
);
insert into TempAB (High, Low, AId)
select high, low, id
from A
where bId is null;

for tempB in (select * from TempAB)
loop
    insert into B (high, low)
    values (tempB.high, tempB.low)
    returning id into newId;
    update A
    set bId=newId
    where id=tempB.AId;
end loop;
end $body$;
rollback;
--commit;
```